# to read json array from html file and printing the values in servlet

Tags: java, javascript, json, servlets

I have a JSON array generated from a form

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(function() {
            $('#btn').click(function() {
                var formData=JSON.stringify($('#sform').serializeObject());
                // $('#rValues').text(formData);
                $.get('Partition',"fdata="+formData,function(fJson) {                   

                    $.each(fJson, function(key,value) { 
                        if(fJson!=null){

                        }
                    });
                });
                $("#rValues").show();              
                return false;
            });
        });
        $.fn.serializeObject = function() {
            var o = {};
            var a = this.serializeArray();
            $.each(a, function () {
                if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
                    if (!o[this.name].push) {
                        o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                    }
                    o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
                } else {
                    o[this.name] = this.value || '';
                }
            });
            return o;
        };
    </script>
```

i'm trying to read and print the entire form values in Partiton.java(servlet) but not able to do so.

```
 String data = request.getParameter("fdata");
    System.out.println(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

you will not get **fdata** by request.getParameter("fdata").

but you will get all form field values by request.getParameter("your form field name given for fields").

**at client side** : to send form data to servlet

```
$.ajax({
     url:'servlet',
     data: $("#form1").serialize(),
     success: function (data) {

    }
});
```

**at servlet** : request.getParameter("your form field name given for form fields").

Comment: the sform is created dynamically so field names are not static. i need the entire array to printed in servlet.

Comment: you can use field ids dynamic and field names static